# Interface method and parameter constraints

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I have an interface and would like to include a method inside it that has a class with parameter constraints. Is it in any way possible to create it in such a way that you do not need to include the constraints in the interface decleration?

```
public interface IPlugin
{
   void InitializeSession(MBROContext context, Reporter<TEntity, TContext> reporter);
}
```

TEntity is a class that inherits from IEntity.
TContext is a DbContext that inherits from IDbcontext.

the signature for the reporter class is as follows:

```
public class Reporter<TEntity, TContext> where TEntity : class, IEntity where TContext : IDbContext, IDisposable, new()
{
    private IUnitOfWork uow;
    private IRepository<TEntity> entryRepository;
    private IService<TEntity> entryService;

    public Reporter()
    {
        this.uow = new UnitOfWork<TContext>();
        this.entryRepository = uow.GetRepository<TEntity>();
        this.entryService = new Service<TEntity>(this.uow);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can specify a concrete type as the generic argument (that meets the given constraints).  If you don't know what the concrete type will be, then no, you don't have a way around making the interface generic (or that one method, in this case, that might be the best option) and having these generic arguments use the same constraints as your `Reporter` type.

If that weren't the case then the constraints could be violated.  If the constraints could be violated then there would be no reason to have constraints in the first place.  The *purpose* of constraints is that they *cannot* be violated.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you cannot. However you could specify interfaces that implements the constraints so as to not be bound to concrete implementations.

In your case for example:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
   void InitializeSession(MBROContext context, Reporter<IEntity, IDbContext> reporter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resorted to the following code as a solution:-)

```
namespace USSDDomain.Core.Abstract.Contracts
{
    public interface IPlugin
    {
        void InitializeSession<TEntity, TContext>(MBROContext context, Reporter<TEntity, TContext> reporter) where TEntity : class,IEntity where TContext : IDbContext, IDisposable, new ();
        void Execute(MBROContext context);
        string CoreCycle(MBROContext context, int stage);
        void ProcessCycle(MBROContext context, int stage, int returnStage);
        void SendResponse(MBROContext context, string xml);
        void PrepareStage(Session session);
    }
}
```

This allows me to call the method in the base class like so:

```
base.InitializeSession(context, new Reporter<Entry, DemoDbContext>());
```

Thanks for taking the time to consider my problem:)

Comment: That is why I did it:-P